# Two models that depend on each other for instantiation

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have two models that depend on each other how am I supposed to be able to create one without creating the other?

```
class Specification < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :prices, inverse_of: :specification
  validates :prices, presence: true

class Price < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :specification, inverse_of: :prices
  validates :specification, presence: true
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialize a Specification instance but don't save it, then initialize an associated Price instance. Finally, save the Specification instance.

```
spec = Specification.new
spec.prices.build
spec.save!
```

(Of course if Specification or Price have other required attributes, you should set them by passing a hash to `new` or `build`, respectively.)

When you save the Specification, its child Price will automatically be saved. Refer to the documentation in [Active Record Autosave Association](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AutosaveAssociation.html#module-ActiveRecord::AutosaveAssociation-label-One-to-many+Example).